# Javascript and PHP promt for MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on creating a JS promt that displays a text box. I would like to be able to take the user input and set it as a php variable to store into mysql.

Javascript:

```
<script>
function newForm(){
var x;

var name=prompt("Please enter a name for your form:");
if (name!=null)  {
    document.getElementById("enteredName").innerHTML=x;
} else {
    window.location.replace("loggedinForms.php");
}
</script>
```

I am able to output the user's input using html:

```
<a href="formp1.php" onclick="myFunction()">Create New Form</a>

<p id="enteredname"></p>
```

How do I assign $formName = the id="enteredName" so I can query the data: `INSERT INTO table_name (form_name) VALUES ('$formName')`?

I think I am over looking something very simple. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you heared about `<form>`?

Comment: Haha yeah, I know about $_POST and have used it throughout the form so far. I wanted to try to expand my knowledge and use of JS for this part of the project.

Comment: So you want to use asynchronus requests (AJAX)?

Comment: Maybe, I havent worked with AJAX that much. This is an example of what I kinda want it to do, but instead of outputting it to the user, query it to mysql: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post it to a php script using ajax...

```
function newForm(){
var x;

var name=prompt("Please enter a name for your form:");
if (name!=null)  {
    document.getElementById("enteredName").innerHTML=x;
    sendVar(enteredName);
} else {
    window.location.replace("loggedinForms.php");
}

var sendVar = function(enteredName){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/yourscript.php,
            async: true,
            data: {
                'formName': enteredName
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .success(function(data,textStatus,XMLHttpRequest) {
            //do something
        })
        .error(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
            //do something
        })
        .complete(function(){
            //do something
        });
}
```

And then on that php script send it to mysql.

EDIT: Forgot to say what you can do on your php script.

Dont forget to check the POST variable on your php script.

```
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
 //grab the variable in post and do mysql
 $formName = $_POST['formName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assign your `<p>` tag value to hidden variable, submit this page by putting `<form>` and insert it into a database.

Answer (score 0):

Best way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
</head>
<body>
<form action="p.php" method="post">
<p>Name: <input type="text" value="" name="name"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Your way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var name =prompt('Enter name:');
$.ajax({
    url:"p.php",
    type:'POST',
    data:{'name':name},
    success: function(e){
        $('#he').html('done');
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="he"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Both submit to p.php

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
    //insert into database
    //echo $_POST['name'];
}else{
    header('Location:p.html');
}
?>
```